# How to take a snapshot of a token

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, erc-20, snapshot

WIth the recent EOS token snapshot, and many other erc20 tokens taking snapshots for airdrops and stuff like that, I'm very curious as to how they actually would go about doing that.

I'm not a programmer/coder by any means, but I understand enough to write a smart contract... (which isn't much really... haha)

I do understand that etherscan shows you the token holders list, but they don't offer a way to export to a csv file, as they do with token transfers.

Already asked etherscan about it...

"You may refer to our available list of APIs here: https://etherscan.io/apis#accounts

However, we are unable to offer token holders for a token at the moment.

Regards"

So, how would a regular joe like me would take a snapshot of a token at a given time?

Comment: I made a snapshot tool for ERC20 Tokens. You can check it out on github https://github.com/Kryptoniq/ERC20-Snapshot

Comment: Current repo: https://github.com/Philipinho/ERC20-Snapshot